# How do I prevent holes in the leaves of my vegetable garden?

Tags: vegetables, pest-control, leaves, pest-damage, leaf-vegetables

Something is eating the leaves of several plants in my vegetable garden. Can you help determine what is causing this and how I can prevent it?

This affects several of my vegetables: Turnips, Lettuce, Spinach, etc.

I live in Los Angeles, CA and this is taking place now (January).

[image: Photo 1]
[image: Photo 2]
[image: Photo 3]
[image: Photo 4]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Get a flashlight and go out at night to find the culprits. Bartholomew, the author of the square foot gardening method, discusses pests in his book

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, **this kind of hole is often caused by slugs**. Slugs stay hidden during the sunlight period and pop out during wet night and rainy days, making them difficult to spot. Note that it can be caterpillar, *thumbtack* (not sure of this translation) or even birds. For identifying the "pest", watch for your plants patiently and minutely.

To fight the slugs, you have a lot of options :

- If there is no big rain planned for next days, spread ashes around your plants - *it dries the slugs and fertilizes growing vegetables*,
- Put beer in little bowl (like bottle cap) at ground level -*slugs love beer and can die ... from ethylic coma*,
- Don't let any bush develop next to your plants - *this their favorite refuge*,
- If you have no other option, buy anti-slug granules.

Comment: The use of beer is very well tested, though you may want more than a bottle cap full. A shallow dish or saucer filled with beer is better IMO.